# Keep Asp.net page life cycle/session objects alive

Tags: c#, asp.net, web-applications, page-lifecycle

I'm heavily using HttpWebRequest in my apps. When my asp.net server receive a httpWebRequest, it uses formsAuthentication to ask the client to login himself and then redirect the page to the default.aspx. I create session objects in the login page and these objects would need to be used in the default.aspx too. The problem is I need to maintain these session objects after the redirection and I'm not able to use FormsAuthentication.RedirectFromloginPage or Response.Redirect. I understand that both syntaxs are able to receive a parameter that keep the page life cycle alive. I can't use these syntaxs as I need to create a response that contains a authentication cookie, then return the response back to the client browser, after that the client browser will navigate to the default.aspx with this authenticaiton cookie. Anyone knows how to keep the sessions objects (or page life cycle) alive without using both syntaxs?

Any response is highly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Use Context.Session to store session variables

Comment: How does context.session would help? I tried both normal session and context.session to store the sessions objects but the objects are gone after redirection. Please advise. Thanks

Comment: This article http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms178581.aspx should help you out.  Search "Configuring Session State"